# How do i get the List array Values based on GID?

Tags: arrays

this is the array structure . How do i get the List array Values based on GID?

Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [GID] => 1
            [List] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [CID] => 24
                            [Name] => Ram
                        )

```
                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [CID] => 33
                        [Name] => Sam
                    )                )
    )
[1] => Array
    (
        [GID] => 2
        [List] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [CID] => 38
                        [Name] => Rohan Seth
                    )
            )
    )
[2] => Array
    (
        [GID] => 3
        [List] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [CID] => 25
                        [Name] => Robin Roy
                    )
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you not write it, so that the GID was the key in the top level of the array, sorta like this?

```
array = [GID][list][0][etc..],
        [GID][list][0][etc..]
```

be warned, pseudo code, as i don't know which language you need it in :)